# Laravel 5.2 conditional in DB query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

When someone writes an entry in the textbox, I want to check the words that they used and find a match in a common word DB that I have. Each word in the DB had a number value that I need it to return.

I need to write an if statement that checks if a query returns a value, and if it does I need it to return -1.

This is what I have so far but right now but it only returns one word.

```
    Entry::create($request->all());

    // GETTING THE ARRY OF WORDS FROM entry_body( $entry_text)
    $entry_text = $request->only('entry_body');

    // REMOVE THE KEY AND JUST GET THE STRING VALUE
    $entry_text = array_pull($entry_text,"entry_body");
    $entry_noTag = strip_tags($entry_text);

    // CONVERTE THE STRING ARRAY
    $entry_explode = explode(" ", $entry_noTag);

    // EACH WORD GETS ANALAYZED 
    $matched_words = Words::whereIn('word', $entry_explode)->get();

    foreach ($entry_explode as $word) {
        if ($matched_words == false){
            return '-1';
        }
        else {
            return $word;
        }
    };
```

I can get the code to return the matched values. What I need it to do is when a word in the array is not matched, it should return -1 so I know the word was not found in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first return will, of course, return and end the function. Put all values in array like this:

```
$arrayOfWords = array();
foreach ($matched_words as $word) {
    if (in_array($word->word,$entry_explode)) {
        $arrayOfWords['found'][] = $word->word;
    } else {
        $arrayOfWords['notFound'][] = $word->word;
    }
}

return $arrayOfWords;
```

Comment: Got it.But I still can not get the other words that are not being matched to return.

Comment: I can get the code to return the matched values. What I need it to do is when a word in the array is not matched, it should return -1 so I know the word was not found in the DB.

Comment: I've made a last edit. Now, you have a array with all words found and not found, just do whatever you need to do with those words.